# Getting cmath errors after updating to Mojave

Tags: c++, xcode

I updated to Mojave yesterday and haven't been able to compile c++ files since then. I am getting the following message :

```
In file included from test.cpp:4:
In file included from /usr/local/include/bits/stdc++.h:10:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:313:9: error: no member named 'signbit' in the global namespace
using ::signbit;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:314:9: error: no member named 'fpclassify' in the global namespace
using ::fpclassify;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cmath:315:9: error: no member named 'isfinite' in the global namespace; did you mean 'finite'?
using ::isfinite;
      ~~^
```

The full message is here at [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/YzJTGE43).

The file test.cpp just prints Hello world and I am using the command "make test" to run it.

**Note:** I do know of threads about similar problems on the net but I am not able to understand them and think that they are too OP-specific.

Comment: Could you please add a minimal version of your test.cpp to your question?

Comment: I am unable to add code while editing, here is the code : https://pastebin.com/UEA8Axtn

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++>` is not standard c++. Where did you even get the header from? It's not part of my Mojave installation.

Comment: I made the bits directory and put the stdc++.h myself however I don't think that is the problems since replacing it with "#include<cmath>" gives the same message.

Comment: If I just `#include <cmath>` (and also remove the `cout` line), it compiles on my machine. Which Xcode Build number (Xcode -> About Xcode) are you using?

Comment: I am using version 10.1 (10B61)

Comment: Still can't reproduce this. Have you any non-default settings in your Xcode project? Otherwise, try to reinstall Xcode...

Comment: Actually I have already tried that (There's still the xcode app in the trash but I am unable to delete that) , is there any another way to delete it completely ?

Comment: I have had the same problem - any updates on your problem, or any workaround or robust solution to date ?

Comment: I had a friend fix it for me , the problem was with some alias of g++ compiler on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue, and researched it quite a bit past couple of weeks. I have found a temporary solution which is different from what is mentioned in the comments.

**Delete/Remove XCode.**

Unfortunately for me this is not a great solution since it's my IDE for C++. However I can't seem to solve it any other way at the moment.

Solution also mentioned here: https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/issues/2601